Gow to remove sorting arrow from Power BI table column header
In Power BI, I'm using a table with 5 columns, but each header column is displaying dropdown arrows for sorting. When I click on them, it sorts all the columns. How can I remove the sorting arrows from the header columns?

I tried unchecking the sort option, but it is not working. I used shapes above the header, but when clicking inside the table, the sorting arrow appears again, and the table gets sorted.

What do you mean by "I have tried unchecking the sort option"? You can't disable sorting

In the Power BI table, there is a 'Sort By' option. When we change it, the sorting arrow is disabled for a few seconds but comes back again if we touch the table

That doesn't disable sorting, just removes current sorting. If you click on the table header again, that column will get sorted. There is no way to disable sorting currently.

The arrow appears because you may click the header to sort.
i think so far we don't have the perfect solution for this. However, here is a workaround : try to remove the column and re-add it to the visual.

